# Multiple mdadm raid rebuild in parallel

Tags: raid, mdadm

I wonder is there any procedure to initiate concurrent rebuild of two or more separate arrays?

while one is rebuilding, another stays in status:

```
md2 : active raid10 sdf5[4] sdd5[6] sdc5[5] sda5[7]
      7804374912 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/3] [_UUU]
      [=====>...............]  recovery = 28.8% (1124301568/3902187456) finish=364.1min speed=127142K/sec

md4 : active raid5 sde7[3](R) sdc7[0] sda7[2] sdb7[1]
      15623708416 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
        recovery=DELAYED
```

any way to start another md array recovery in parallel?

UPDATE 1:

Thanks to accepted answer I have huge time saving:

```
md2 : active raid10 sdb5[8](R) sdf5[4] sdd5[6] sdc5[5] sda5[7]
      7804374912 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      [===============>.....]  recovery = 78.9% (3079104384/3902187456) finish=123.8min speed=110796K/sec

md4 : active raid5 sde7[3](R) sdc7[0] sda7[2] sdb7[1]
      15623708416 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.0% (3492100/7811854208) finish=708.0min speed=183794K/sec
```

Still I had very interesting issues because of my different trial actions before, which will post in separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should run in parallel, if truly separate (different sets of physical drives).

However, when multiple arrays share the same drives (different partitions of the same drive), the rebuilds are delayed, since running in parallel here would not speed things up, but slow them down instead.

You can force resyncs to run in parallel anyway by setting the sync_force_parallel flag.

```
echo 1 | tee > /sys/block/md*/md/sync_force_parallel
```

Comment: Yes, you are right in general, but if you have situation when physically different raid members participate in different mdraid reshape/replacement then it is faster in paralllel.

Answer (score 0):

The frostschutz answer was stright to the point, I immediately got parallel rebuild started, but even there should no be impact, the speed of first array rebuild suddenly dropped 10 times!

```
md2 : active raid10 sdb5[8](R) sdf5[4] sdd5[6] sdc5[5] sda5[7]
      7804374912 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      [===============>.....]  recovery = 75.3% (2941270464/3902187456) finish=1723.0min speed=9294K/sec

md4 : active raid5 sde7[3](R) sdc7[0] sda7[2] sdb7[1]
      15623708416 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      [=>...................]  recovery =  6.9% (542682052/7811854208) finish=692.7min speed=174889K/sec
```

I could not understand why I had an impact, until I saw mdadm -D details of array, and suddenly realized that it started rebuilding wrong drive.

Tried failing removing, clearing superblock of replacement and adding as spare new drive few times, and still it started to replace wrong drive.

Then I found out that I can view md array per drive state:

```
#cat /sys/block/md4/md/rd?/state
in_sync
in_sync,want_replacement
in_sync,want_replacement
```

that was it! I was experimenting with different drives as target in different positions, and accordingly I tried data migration from different md drive to different target, then cancel operation, but when I issue mdadm /dev/mdX --replace /dev/sdX drive is marked as `want_replacement` and system does not forget about that, but I do :D

So clearing flag with:

```
# echo -want_replacement > /sys/block/md4/md/rd1/state
# cat /sys/block/md4/md/rd?/state
in_sync
in_sync
in_sync,want_replacement
```

put everything into place, and adding spare drive now starts replacement of correct drive with all speeds in parallel maxed out:

```
# mdadm /dev/md4 --add /dev/sde7
# mdadm -D /dev/md4
...
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       39        0      active sync   /dev/sdc7
       1       8       23        1      active sync   /dev/sdb7
       2       8        7        2      active sync   /dev/sda7
       3       8       71        2      spare rebuilding   /dev/sde7

# cat /proc/mdstat
md2 : active raid10 sdb5[8](R) sdf5[4] sdd5[6] sdc5[5] sda5[7]
      7804374912 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      [===============>.....]  recovery = 78.9% (3079104384/3902187456) finish=123.8min speed=110796K/sec

md4 : active raid5 sde7[3](R) sdc7[0] sda7[2] sdb7[1]
      15623708416 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.0% (3492100/7811854208) finish=708.0min speed=183794K/sec
```